# drawing charts with nonlinear scale in php or js

Tags: php, javascript, charts

does anybody known charts library, which I can manually set X or Y scale intervals between values? I have to draw chart but for example interval between 1 to 10 is twice bigger then from 20 to 30. So I would like to be able set manually scale interval?

Comment: Have you tried [Google Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) ?

Comment: highcharts.com? Very good javascript graphing lib. You can certainly set the scaling but not sure if you can do it between ticks...

Comment: @Teneff google charts cant do it

Comment: @nickhar I know highcharts, but I can only scale the whole axis..